# Creating stl mesh file with textures

Tags: ros, urdf, stl, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make a simple cube to set over a pioneer. The cube has some Aruco Tags (textures). I did the cube in sketchup and them exported it to stl. Then I saved it with meshlab and put it in my robot.

Problem--> the cube doesn't have the textures (Arucos tags) I put in sketchup. How do you export the file with the textures included anyone knows?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203681/creating-stl-mesh-file-with-textures/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-02-24**:
update- tried making a .dae with sketchup. Fails to load in meshlab, says it doesn't have the textures. Collada files are really complicated. Putting a texture on a robot is really hard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"STL files describe only the surface geometry of a three-dimensional object without any representation of color, texture or other common CAD model attributes" ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29)). If you'd like to represent textures, you'll need to use a different file format, like Collada, which is well supported by the ROS tools.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-02-24**:
So I used the wrong program. Maybe I can add up the texture with Meshlab. What program do you recommend to generate the mesh with the textures?

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-02-24**:
Meshlab has tools for projecting images to geometry ([online tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJZRuIzHcVw), untested by myself), and can export to Collada. There are many other open source (Blender) and proprietary (3DS max, Maya, Rhino, ...) applications that can do the job.

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-02-24**:
I tried with blender. Blender can't export to .dae. At least I don't see that option.

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-02-25**:
Made it man!

Thx so much anyway.

http://answers.ros.org/question/203702/mesh-dae-file-with-textures-invisible/?answer=203775#post-id-203775

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

STL doesn't support textures (well, 'official' STL doesn't), it only encodes surface geometry, no colour, no textures.

Colours can be set (at least in RViz, and on the entire mesh) using the `color` element in a URDF.

If you really want to texture your meshes, you'll have to use another format (RViz also supports `.dae` (Collada) and Ogre `.mesh`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2